# Making a panel stretch to the size of the canvas and then back to its previous size like a "maximize" button in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, canvas, maximize-window

I've figured out how to make the maximize portion of this work using the aspect ratio built in function on a button to scale a panel up to the full size of the screen. Haven't been able to find anywhere how to get it to back down to its previous size.

Comment: Remember it’s original size and place?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.